# Variable Assignment in a Loop

Tags: shell, unix, variable-assignment

I am writing a shell script that reads and reports out timestamps (the current timestamp is stored in `$g2`).  Eventually I will be comparing the two timestamps.

I want to check if `$t2` is empty - if it is, the store it as `$g2`.
If not, then to replace `$t2` as `$t1`, and store the new `$g2` value as `$t2`.

I am trying to output this in a sudo csv style file - but when I attempt to run this script I keep getting command not found errors.  Any suggestions?

```
if
    [[ -z "$t2" ]]
then
    $t2=$g2
    echo "$t1,0,0" >> just_time.txt
else
    $t2=$t1
    $t2=$g2
    echo "$t2,$t1,0" >> just_time.txt
fi
```

Comment: `$t2` = replaced by the value of t2. So you want `t2=$g2` and not `$t2=$g2`.

Comment: Thanks for this - but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
if
    [[ -z "$t2" ]]
then
    t2=$g2
    echo "$t1,0,0" >> just_time.txt
else
    t1=$t2
    t2=$g2
    echo "$t2,$t1,0" >> just_time.txt
fi
```

Comment: That has only just printed a single timestamp on each line.

Comment: Can you post your whole shell script and the error you are getting?